# Prove Euler's reflection formula with complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Does it possible to prove the Euler's reflection formula
$$ \Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z} \;\;\text{  for  }\;\; 0<\mathrm{Re}(z)<1$$
without any double integrals or Weierstrass product ? A proof based on complex analysis...
If someone has references or any ideas, I am interested :)

Comment: In what ways are double (complex contour integrals) _not_ complex analysis?

Comment: Regardless, some of [these](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76399/one-line-proof-of-the-eulers-reflection-formula) may interest you.

Comment: How is $\Gamma(z)$ defined? That is, what properties of it are we allowed to use?

Comment: $\Gamma$ is defined as the analytic continuation of $z\mapsto \int_0^\infty t^{z-1}\mathrm e^{-t}\,\mathrm dt$ valid for $\mathrm{Re}(z)>0$...

Comment: I like [thisone](https://mathoverflow.net/a/76447/84768) mentioned by Mark : $f(s) = \Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)\sin(\pi s)$ is a $1$-periodic entire function, thus $f(s) = F(e^{2i \pi s})$ where $F(z)$ is analytic on $|z| > 0$ and $F(z) = \mathcal{O}(|z|^{-1/2}+|z|^{1/2})$, so $z F(z)$ is entire as well as $F$ which is $\mathcal{O}(1+|z|^{1/2})$ and hence constant. Now showing the Weierstrass product for $\Gamma$ stays a good idea.

Comment: They have the same Laurent series expansion
$\quad\frac{\pi }{\sin (\pi  z)}=\frac{7 \pi ^4 z^3}{360}+\frac{\pi ^2 z}{6}+\frac{1}{z}+O(z^5)\quad$ and $\quad\Gamma (1-z) \Gamma (z)=\frac{7 \pi ^4 z^3}{360}+\frac{\pi ^2 z}{6}+\frac{1}{z}+O(z^5)$